# Visual Studio 2015 android emulator doesn't start in HYPER V environment

Tags: android-emulator, virtual-machine, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

my VS2015 is installed within a Win8.1 virtual machine (created with hyper-V, host system windows 2012 R2).

When I try to start the VS Android Emulator I get a german error message - rough translation:

'the emulator can't check if the virtual computer is executed.

Failure while starting a virtual computer "VS Emulator 7-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet.iwp(ID of the virtual computer ...

The virtual computer "VS Emulator 7-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet.iwp" couldn't be started by the administration service because a hyper v component isn't executed'

Can anybody tell, what's the problem? Hyper-V is installed, I started the Hyper V manager, looks fine. I have no idea how to start the emulator right now.

Best regards

Pellaeon

Answer (score 1):

Per the VS Emulator for Android System Requirements (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx), you can't run the emulator (which is a VM) inside of a VM.